# Question regarding a step in Wikipedia's proof of the Radon-Nikodym Theorem

Tags: integration, measure-theory, proof-explanation, sequence-of-function

I have a question regarding [Wikipedia's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#For_finite_measures) of the Radon-Nikodym theorem for finite measures:

Why does there exist a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ in $F$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n\ d\mu = \sup_{f\in F}\int f\ d\mu?$$

Comment: @DarkMagician oh, of course. Feel free to add that as an answer.

Comment: Ok, moved to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just the definition of $\sup$. It can be approximated arbitrarily well taking appropriate elements of $F$. If it is $<+\infty$, we can take $f_n \in F$ s.t.
$$\int f_n d\mu > \sup_{f\in F} \int f d\mu-\frac{1}{n}$$

while if it is $+\infty$  we can take $f_n \in F$ s.t.
$$\int f_n d\mu >n$$